# Swift SpriteKit 衝突処理（didBegin）が動作しない

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

NodeAの体力をNodeBと接触する度に減らし、NodeAの体力が０になった瞬間にNodeAを消滅、といった処理を行いたいです。
どうやら、一度接触する度に値がリセットされてしまい、NodeAの体力が０にならないようです。
下記詳細になります。
（NodeAをasteroidLife 、NodeBをmissile　としています。）

Swift SpriteKit 衝突処理（didBegin）にて、asteroid(Node)に値（Life）の情報を加え、missile(Node)と衝突される度にasteroid(Node)の値を減らし、値が0になった時点でasteroid(Node)を消滅、といったコードを書きたいです。
（下記コードで試しました。）

```
var asteroidLife: Int = 100 // asteroidの体力
let missilePW: Int = 50     // missileの攻撃力

if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
    tagetNode.removeFromParent()
    asteroidLife -= missilePW

    if asteroidLife <= 0 {
        asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

上記のコードでは１度接触する度にasteroidLifeがリセットされてしまい、　if asteroidLife <= 0 　が実行されません。

１度目の接触にて更新されたasteroidLifeの値を２度目の接触でも使用できるようになれば、、と思っておりますが、方法が思いつきません。

何かいい方法はありますでしょうか。

一応全コードを下に添付致します。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var gameVC: GameViewController!

    var spaceship:SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship") 
    var button : SKSpriteNode! 
    var LifeLabel: SKLabelNode!

    let spaceshipCategory : UInt32 = 0b0001
    let missileCategory : UInt32 = 0b0010
    let asteroidCategory  : UInt32 = 0b0100

    var Life: Int = 500 {
        didSet {
            LifeLabel.text = "Life: \(Life)"
        }
    }

    var timar: Timer?

    func DegreeToRadian(Degree : Double!) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(Degree) / CGFloat(180.0 * M_1_PI)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black 

        self.spaceship.alpha = 1 
        self.spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / -2 + 100, y: view.frame.height / -2 + 100) 
        self.spaceship.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150) 
        self.spaceship.zRotation = DegreeToRadian(Degree: 0)
        self.spaceship.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
        self.spaceship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.spaceship.frame.width * 0.1) 
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = spaceshipCategory
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory

        self.spaceship.name  = "spaceship"
        self.addChild(self.spaceship) 

        self.button = self.childNode(withName: "button") as? SKSpriteNode 

        if let button = self.button {
            button.name = "button" 
            button.alpha = 0.0 
            button.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0)) 
        }

        LifeLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Life:500")
        LifeLabel.fontSize = 50
        LifeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -frame.width / 2 + LifeLabel.frame.width + 50, y: frame.height / 2 - 200)
        addChild(LifeLabel)

        timar = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.addasteroid()
        })

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isPaused { return }

        if let touch = touches.first { 
            let locatin = touch.location(in: self) 
            if self.atPoint(locatin).name == "button" { 

                let missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "missile")
                missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: missile.frame.height / 2 ) 
                missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = missileCategory
                missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
                missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory

                missile.position = CGPoint(x: self.spaceship.position.x , y: self.spaceship.position.y + 10 )
                missile.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75) 
                addChild(missile)

                let topButton = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.height + 10 , duration: 0.3)
                let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent() 
                missile.run(SKAction.sequence([topButton, remove])) 

                if self.atPoint(locatin).name == "spaceship" {
                    return
                }

            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first 
        let buttonLocation = touch?.location(in: self)  
        switch self.atPoint(buttonLocation!).name == "button" { 
            case true:
                break

            default:
                let location = touches.first!.location(in: self) 
                let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y:location.y + 20), duration: 0.1) 
                spaceship.run(action) 
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)
    }

    func addasteroid() {

        let names = ["asteroid1","asteroid2","asteroid3"]
        let index = Int.random(in: 0...2) 
        let name = names[index] 
        let asteroid = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)

        let XHighest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 2 - spaceship.size.width 
        let XLowest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / -2 + spaceship.size.width 
        let random = CGFloat.random(in: XLowest...XHighest) 
        asteroid.position = CGPoint(x: random, y: frame.width) 
        asteroid.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) 

        asteroid.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: asteroid.frame.width)
        asteroid.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory

        addChild(asteroid) 

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.width / -2 - 100, duration: 1.0) 
        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        asteroid.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var asteroid: SKPhysicsBody
        var target: SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
            asteroid = contact.bodyA
            target = contact.bodyB

        } else {
            asteroid = contact.bodyB
            target = contact.bodyA
        }

        guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node else { return }
        guard let tagetNode = target.node else { return }
        guard let Bakuhatu = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bakuhatu") else { return }
        Bakuhatu.position = asteroidNode.position
        addChild(Bakuhatu)

        var asteroidLife: Int = 100
        let missilePW: Int = 50

        if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
            tagetNode.removeFromParent()
            asteroidLife -= missilePW

            if asteroidLife <= 0 {
                asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
            Bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
        }

        if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            Life -= 100

            if Life <= 0 {
                GameOver()
            }

        }

    }

    func GameOver() {
        isPaused = true
        timar?.invalidate()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { _ in
            self.gameVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameover", sender: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在お示しいただいたコードのように、`var asteroidLife: Int = 100`と言うローカル変数を宣言すれば、その変数は「値がリセットされ」るどころか、変数のスコープを抜け出すと変数自体がなくなってしまいます。

かと言って、`Life`のように`GameScene`クラスのインスタンス変数にしてしまうと、シーンごとに一つのライフしか管理できなくなるので、asteroidが多数でるあなたのゲームには使えないでしょう。(配列等を用意すると言う手もありますが、コードがどんどん複雑になるので、やめておいた方が無難です。余談ですが、Swiftでは型名以外の識別子は小文字で始めるのが普通です。かなり広く守られているルールなので、守られていないあなたのコードは(Swift経験者にとって)非常に読みづらいものとなってしまいます。)

---

「個々のasteroidがそれぞれ個別のライフを持つ」と言う状態は、オブジェクト指向には格好の題材で、今回の場合であれば、

- **asteroid専用のクラスを作ってやる**

と言うのが最も適した方法であるように思われます。

こんな感じで、asteroid専用のクラス(`SKSpriteNode`のサブクラス)を定義してやります。

```
class AsteroidNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var life: Int = 100
}
```

後は、

- asteroidを生成するときには、`SKSpriteNode`ではなく、`AsteroidNode`を使う
- asteroidのライフを操作する場合には、`AsteroidNode`の`life`プロパティを使う

と言う修正を行うだけです。

```
    func addasteroid() {

        let names = ["asteroid1","asteroid2","asteroid3"]
        let index = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        let name = names[index]
        let asteroid = AsteroidNode(imageNamed: name) //<- `SKSpriteNode`ではなく、`AsteroidNode`にする

        let xHighest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 2 - spaceship.size.width
        let xLowest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / -2 + spaceship.size.width
        let random = CGFloat.random(in: xLowest...xHighest)
        asteroid.position = CGPoint(x: random, y: frame.width)
        asteroid.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

        asteroid.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: asteroid.frame.width)
        asteroid.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory

        addChild(asteroid)

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.width / -2 - 100, duration: 1.0)
        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        asteroid.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var asteroid: SKPhysicsBody
        var target: SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
            asteroid = contact.bodyA
            target = contact.bodyB

        } else {
            asteroid = contact.bodyB
            target = contact.bodyA
        }

        guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node as? AsteroidNode else { return } //<- `AsteroidNode`になっていることを確認
        guard let targetNode = target.node else { return }
        guard let bakuhatu = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bakuhatu") else { return }
        bakuhatu.position = asteroidNode.position
        addChild(bakuhatu)

        let missilePW: Int = 50

        if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
            targetNode.removeFromParent()
            asteroidNode.life -= missilePW //<- ローカル変数ではなく`AsteroidNode`のインスタンス変数を操作する

            if asteroidNode.life <= 0 { //<- 〃
                asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
            bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
        }

        if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            Life -= 100

            if Life <= 0 {
                GameOver()
            }

        }

    }
```

将来のことを考えると、`SpaceshipNode`クラスや`MissileNode`クラスも定義した方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。
お陰様で無事こちらの問題を解決する事ができました！
また、コードの書き方に対するアドバイスもありがとうございます。勉強になります。
今後ともよろしくお願いいたします！！

Comment: @sho さん、ご丁寧にありがとうございます。こうやって動作報告をいただけると、少し時間をとって回答を書いた甲斐があると感じることができます。これからご質問を続けられると、期待通りには動かない回答を目にすることもあるかと思いますが、そんな場合でも、無言や「動かない」の一言だけでなく、どうなってしまって、どんな点が期待する動作と違うのかを丁寧に説明すると、期待する動作になるまで回答をアップデートしてもらえることもあります。サイトをうまく利用して良いアプリを作ってください。

Comment: OOPerさん、始めたばかりで質問の方法もよくわかっていなかったので、非常に有難いアドバイスです。ありがとうございます。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。